# Let $V \subset \mathcal{P}^n$ be a complete intersection of dimension $d$, then $H^i(V,\mathcal{O}_V)=0$ for $0<i<d$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Beauville's "Complex Algebraic Surfaces", and I am a bit stuck at the proof of Lemma VIII.9. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Let $V \subset \mathcal{P}^n$ be a complete intersection of dimension $d$, then $H^i(V,\mathcal{O}_V)=0$ for $0<i<d$.

Beauville proceeds by induction on the number of equations defining $V$, in fact proving the more general $H^i(V,\mathcal{O}_V(k))=0$ for $0<i<d$ and $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Let $W \subset V$ is a hypersurface in $V$ of degree $r$, then then he implies that the conclusion follows from the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_V(k-r) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_V(k) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_W(k) \rightarrow 0$, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the short exact sequence
$$0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_V(k-r) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_V(k) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_W(k) \longrightarrow 0$$
Taking the long exact sequence on cohomology, we have
$$\cdots \longrightarrow H^i(V,\mathcal{O}_V(k)) \longrightarrow H^i(W,\mathcal{O}_W(k)) \longrightarrow H^{i+1}(V,\mathcal{O}_V(k-r)) \longrightarrow \cdots$$
Now $H^i(V,\mathcal{O}_V(k)) = 0$ for all $0 < i < d+1$ and all $k$ by induction, and so exactness in the sequence above shows $H^i(W,\mathcal{O}_W(k)) = 0$ for all $0 < i < d$.